# stretching div to fill body

Tags: css, layout, html

```
<html style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <body style="height:100%;width:100%;">
        <div style="height:20px;background-color:red;"></div>
        <div style="background-color:black;"></div>
        <div style="height:20px;background-color:blue;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make the second div stretch to fill remaining space (after placing the first and third div) in the body?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the stick footer system, then use this technique:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -20px;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 20px;
}
```

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your *intent* properly (who knows..):

[***Live Demo***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yzf4x/show/light/) ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/yzf4x/))

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="mid"></div>
<div id="bot"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body {
    color: #fff
}

#top, #mid, #bot {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
}

#top {
    height: 20px;
    background: red;

    top: 0;
}
#mid {
    background: #000;

    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px
}
#bot {
    height: 20px;
    background: blue;

    bottom: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use all % or all pixels(find screen pixel height in js)

```
 <html style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <body style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    <div style="height:3%;background-color:red;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:black; height:94%;"></div>
    <div style="height:3%;background-color:blue;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Other perfect answer derived from above answer

```
<html >
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -20px;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 20px;
}
.header {
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
<body >

<div class="wrapper" style="background-color:#ffcc00">
   <div class="header" style="background-color:#cccccc"></div>
   <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer" style="background-color:#cccccc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```